# How to wrap around a ring buffer?

Tags: c, algorithm, memory, circular-buffer

I am trying to implement a ring buffer in C to an external flash memory. For reference the flash memory is BR24G32-3 with 4kb.

I am having difficulties when it comes to the wrap around. After writing to all addresses 0x0000 ~ 0x1000, when it comes to wrap around and writes over the oldest data, my checking causes an infinite loop.

What I see my algorithm doing:

- Check the head position with ringbuf_head_position();
- Write to the head position
- Check if was written, if yes, increment 0x20 write to the next position.

How can I improve this algorithm? I am looking to fix the error when I finish writing to the end address 0x1000 and when I reset to 0x0000, my ring buffer is already finding WRITTEN (0x31) flag at every block of data.

Thank you in advance.

```
void rb_write_to_flash(ring_buffer_t *rb)
{
    uint8_t base_head_address[2] = {0x01, 0x0C};
    ringbuf_head_position(head_position); // Load initial state of the ring buffer

    if (head_position[0] == 0xFF && head_position[1] == 0xFF)
    {
        NRF_LOG_INFO("HEAD == 0xFF");
        head_position[0] = 0x00;
        head_position[1] = 0x00;
    }

    // Convert head_position to a uint16_t value
    uint16_t head_pos_value = ((uint16_t)head_position[0] << 8) | head_position[1];

    do
    {
        // Check if position has been written
        nrf_drv_twi_tx(&m_twi, EEPROM_ADDRESS, head_position, 2, true);
        nrf_drv_twi_rx(&m_twi, EEPROM_ADDRESS, head_buffer, sizeof(head_buffer));

        if (head_buffer[28] == WRITTEN)
        {
            NRF_LOG_INFO("HEAD ALREADY WRITTEN");

            // Increment position by 0x20
            head_pos_value += 0x20;
            if (head_pos_value >= 0x1000) // Checking for overflow
            {
                NRF_LOG_INFO("WRAPPING AROUND");
                head_pos_value = 0x00; // Reset if it exceeds 0xFFFF
                uint8_t initial_address[2] = {0x00, 0x00};
                write_record(base_head_address, initial_address, 2);

                // Clear the WRITTEN flag for the first position in EEPROM
                uint8_t clear_buffer[30] = {0xFF}; // Assuming 0xFF is the default/empty state
                write_record(initial_address, clear_buffer, sizeof(clear_buffer));
            }

            NRF_LOG_INFO("HEAD POSITION: 0x%04x", head_pos_value);

            // Convert back to array
            head_position[0] = (head_pos_value >> 8) & 0xFF;
            head_position[1] = head_pos_value & 0xFF;
        }

    } while (head_buffer[28] == WRITTEN);

    // Write data to the correct position
    rb->buffer[0].written = WRITTEN; // Set flag as written
    write_record(head_position, (uint8_t *)rb->buffer, sizeof(rb->buffer));

    // Write the new head position to flash memory
    write_record(base_head_address, head_position, 2);
}
```

Comment: Here's my personal best ring buffer implementation if you want to study it: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/containers_ring_buffer_FIFO_GREAT.c

Comment: My `ring_buffer_write_safe()` checks for overwrite. Seems like you only looked at a little bit of my file. It took me 10 years to write that code, with hundreds of hours on that topic alone. So, I recommend you spend more than 10 minutes looking at it. As for your specific case, unfortunately I don't have time to take a detailed look right now. Don't give up.

Comment: What is the definition of `head_position`, and why is it an array? Its definition is not in your code in the question.

Comment: Same with `ringbuf_head_position`, `nrf_drv_twi_tx()`, `nrf_drv_twi_rx()`, `head_buffer`, `WRITTEN`, etc. It seems the code presented in the question is not complete. I can't follow what's going on in the code nor what the intended design and approach is.